# Хранение динамического набора параметров в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим, если нужно хранить динамический набора параметров, опций, whatever, привязанных к одной сущности, какой подход для этого будет лучше?. В голову приходят такие варианты:

1. serialize()
2. json_encode()
3. создать таблицу для хранения типа параметра и связать ее с нужной сущностю через промежуточную таблицу
4. что-то, до чего я не додумался

Очень интересно услышать мнения, какой из подходов лучше и почему.

Comment: если поиск и выборки средствами СУБД нужен, то первый да и второй мимо.

Comment: да, справедливое замечание, но хотелось бы узнать, какой вариант в целом логичнее юзать. На практике встречался с первым и остался не в восторге

Comment: Вы не озвучили самое главное - что именно с этими данными будет делаться. А просто хранить - пофиг как, лишь бы без потерь.

Comment: На практике надо использовать тот, который подходит конкретно под вашу задачу. А что бы это определить надо представить весь возможный набор, хотя бы частых запросов к этой БД. Что вы делаете с данными чаще, ищите по конкретным атрибутам, добавляете новые данные, обновляете старые с воздействием на минимум атрибутов, выбираете один объект со всеми атрибутами, выбираете множество объектов со всеми (большинством) атрибутов. В крайних случаях возможны даже варианты с хранением данных как в EAV, так и их копии в сериализованном (как либо, включая json) виде.

Comment: А еще вопрос поддерживает ли ваша версия MySQL прямые операции с json

Comment: вероятнее всего будут выполнятся все вышеперечисленные действия, т.е. выборка одного объекта со всеми атрибутами и всех объектов со всеми/большинством атрибутов. Поиск по атрибутам так же, думается, будет актуален @Mike

Comment: Ну тогда как раз смешанный вариант лучше делать. при выборке объекта броать все из сериализованного представления. А при поиске использование структуры EAV гораздо эффективнее (при наличии  индекса по значению)